# Store root scope data in browser local/ session storage and load after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, browser-cache

Team, We have implemented a single page application, where we are storing some data in root scope to access in other pages of an application. Everything works fine in normal flow. We hit the problem on browser refresh. When user in one of our application pages, if user refreshes the page, whole data is lost from root scope. We tried not allowing to refresh. But, we found that it is not possible and not even able add custom message to notify the user. Now, we are just logging out the user whenever he refresh the page, which is an awkward to user and that too our application doesn't need that much security. So, we are thinking to add whole root scope data in local storage on refreshing the page and after reloading the page, we would again load whole data from local/ session storage data to root scope. We have to do this at single place. So, we don't have to implement this at individual module page.
Is there a way to achieve this. Can any one please suggest if have an alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that HTML5 Local Storage only has 800kb-10mb depending on the browser. I heard Safari has 99 idk. 5mb in the latest Google Chrome (2/14/17).

Anyway, you can create a local storage by stringifying to JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem('myDataStorage', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

Then retrieve them

```
var myRetrievedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage'));
```

myDataStorage is the name of your created localStorage. You can use different names to create multiple localStorages if you would, just be aware that each one is limited only in size. Don't expect to save HD images much less videos using HTML local storage

That being done, your retrieved data can now be manipulated by your code using the variable myRetrievedData (or whatever variable name you want)